# linux split data and get expected output

Tags: linux

```
 "1560880011316","m1_1560880011316"
 "1568622914951","m3_1568622914951"
 "1561241144148","m9_1561241144148"
 "1565872821276","m10_1565872821276"
 "1569150947729","m40_1569150947729"
 "1568629593352","m72_1568629593352"
 "1557672414555","m76_1560947193769"
 "1557151559940","m17_1561077860973"
```

From the data first column (seperated by ",") is the timestamp . i want to extract all ids (starting with m) where timestamp doesnt match the timestamp with the ids (seperated with "_") in linux
For example for the above data the result should be 
m76_1560947193769
m17_1561077860973

As only the above 2 are not as expected.

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? And where's the [mcve] of your attempt? Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Oh, and what "are not..."? Seems like you cut off a sentence there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tag is "linux" only, without any programming language specified. I assume you are expecting some Linux command line based solution: To read lines, then to split into two columns - timestamp and id, then to match timestamp against id and to output those unmatched. There should be a lot Linux commands can do above - awk, sed, grep, native shell. Here below is one based on native bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
export IFS=" ,"
while read tm id; do
    [[ "${id//\"}" =~ "m[0-9]+_${tm//\"}" ]] || echo $tm,$id
done
```

Then run the script (e.g. check_unmatch.sh) with input text (e.g. input.txt) as `./check_unmatch.sh < input.txt` (chmod in before of course).

Note:

1. The space inside `IFS=" ,"` is intended to remove the heading space in your original input. The comma is of course the delimiter of columns.
2. The `"${id//\"}"` is to remove the double quote, so be the `${tm//\"}`.
3. The regex is to check as strictly as your example describes. It can be tailored.

Comment: thanks , yes i was expecting linux command only like this , i tried like this : sh main.sh < ch.txt . but it is not giving the expected result . It is just printing whatever the input is .